# How to mix/fix IComparable and IComparable<T> mess

Tags: c#, generics, icomparable

I have a helper function, which basically calls CompareTo on two objects, but does some special corner case checking, converting, etc.

Originally I wrote the function as such:

```
public static bool BetterCompare(IComparable lhs, IComparable rhs, out retCode)
{
    ...
    retCode = lhs.CompareTo(rhs);
    ...
}
```

But the problem is that if I have a `class AwesomeClass : IComparable<AwesomeClass>`. In fact I have several as some older `IComparable` classes have gone `IComparable<T>`. Yet the compiler gets angry because it can't convert these new objects to `IComparable`. I don't know if this makes it worse, but some of them are `abstract` (though the abstract class does provide an implementation).

How can I convey "I want two objects that I can call CompareTo on" and not have the compiler give me any lip. Preferably, the new function should NOT look like `BetterCompare<AwesomeClass>(this, that, out retCode);`,  but just "do the right thing". Or is there a better way to do this without touching every class making them *both* `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>`?

Comment: you could overload methods, but you want a better solution than that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either make `AwesomeClass` implement the nongeneric `IComparable` interface as well as `IComparable<T>`, or you can write a generic `BetterCompare` method:

```
public static bool BetterCompare<T>(T lhs, T rhs, out retCode)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    ...
    retCode = lhs.CompareTo(rhs);
    ...
}
```

(Note that this can live alongside your existing method.)

Comment: Thanks. I tried using Generics to solve the problem, but I didn't remember to qualify(?) T.

Comment: Not *really* there just yet - 74951 at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always change the variables to an object type and then use reflection to see if they  implement one of the interfaces and then cast them to the correct interface.

NOTE: Reflection is crazy slow, so use it with caution.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [`Comparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx), that implements both `IComparer<T>` and `IComparer`, and use that in the appropriate places. It may require some refactoring of your code though.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx) says:

The object returned by the Default property uses the `System.Collections.Generic.IComparable<T>` generic interface to compare two objects. If type T does not implement the `IComparable<T>` generic interface, the Default property returns a `Comparer<T>` that uses the `System.Collections.IComparable` interface.